# Custom method struts2 rest plugin

Tags: java, rest, struts2

Like [default](http://struts.apache.org/docs/rest-plugin.html#RESTPlugin-RESTfulURLMappingLogic) mapping logic, I want to create my own custom method for rest service.

1. Default method to edit new movie: **GET: /movies/new => method=editNew**
2. My custom method: **GET: /movies/customMethod => method=customMethod**

The custom method not allow ID parameter.

Other custom method:

3. My custom method: **POST: /movies/{ID}/customMethod => method=customMethod**
4. My custom method: **GET: /movies/{ID}/actors => method=actorOfOneMovie**

My configuration:

```
  <constant name="struts.mapper.class" value="org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.PrefixBasedActionMapper" />
  <constant name="struts.mapper.prefixMapping" value="/api:rest, :struts"/>
  <constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false" />
  <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="false" />
  <constant name="struts.convention.action.suffix" value="Action, Controller" />
  <constant name="struts.convention.action.mapAllMatches" value="true" />
  <constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="rest-default" />
  <constant name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="api" />
  <constant name="struts.rest.namespace" value="/api" />
  <constant name="struts.rest.defaultExtension" value="json" />
```

and relative package:

```
  <package name="api" namespace="/api" extends="rest-default">
<result-types>
  <result-type name="redirect"
    class="org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletRedirectResult">
    <param name="statusCode">303</param>
  </result-type>
  <result-type name="redirectAction"
    class="org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletActionRedirectResult">
    <param name="statusCode">303</param>
  </result-type>
</result-types>
<action name="movies/*" class="api.MoviesController">
<param name="id">{1}</param> 
</action>
```

With this configuration, examples 1, 3 and 4 are working properly.
If I call the example 2, struts2 maps the URL with the default method **show**.

Questions:

1. Is there a configuration that permits my case - i.e., creating a customMethod?
2. Is it possible to restrict `http` requests to a specific VERB?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Added configuration and question.